# Delete Child entity Record in EF core after comparing

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Child entity of Aggregate Entity with one-to-many relation, and in the child, there is a list containing the parent id. the data coming from the front-end is a list of object and if it is no different from what comes to back-end I will do nothing with it. otherwise, I will remove what has been removed and add what has been added to the table.

[image]

I am new at EF CORE and I am trying to apply this login in this relation.

```
if (child.list.SuccessorId == parent.vehicleCategoryId) => ignore;
if(!child.list.contain(parent.vehicleCategoryId)
 remove(parent.vehicleCategoryId) => //delete record with vehicleCategoryId
  else 
    add(child)
```

here is my entities.

```
public class VehicleCategory : LookupAggregateRoot<VehicleCategory>
{
    #region Constructor

    private VehicleCategory()
    {
        _successors = new List<VehicleSuccessorCategory>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Data

    public virtual LocalizedText Name { get; set; }
    public virtual long Sequence { get; set; }
    private readonly List<VehicleSuccessorCategory> _successors;

    public IEnumerable<VehicleSuccessorCategory> Successors
    {
        get => _successors.AsReadOnly();
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Behaviour

    public void AddSuccessor(VehicleSuccessorCategory entrySuccessorCategory)
    {
        _successors.Add(entrySuccessorCategory);

    }

    public void RemoveSuccessor(VehicleSuccessorCategory entrySuccessorCategory)
    {
        _successors.Remove(entrySuccessorCategory);
    }
}


public class VehicleSuccessorCategory : ID365Entity<int>, IEnumerable
{
    #region Constructor

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SuccessorId { get; set; }
    public VehicleSuccessorCategory(int order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Data

    public int Order { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public bool IsTransient()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Id;
        yield return Order;
    }
}
```

I tried

```
 VehicleCategory vehicleCategory = _genericRepository.Get(aggregate.Id);
        foreach (var successorCategory in aggregate.Successors)
        {
            var successorCategoryToRemove =
                vehicleCategory.Successors.Where(e => e.SuccessorId == successorCategory.SuccessorId);
            foreach (var vehicleSuccessorCategory in successorCategoryToRemove)
                vehicleCategory.RemoveSuccessor(vehicleSuccessorCategory);
        }
```